# Check if memcached is installed?

Tags: php, installation, memcached, syntax-error

I used [this](http://forums.zpanelcp.com/Thread-How-to-install-memcache-centos) guide to install memcached on Centos 6.5

I first checked

```
/etc/init.d/memcached status and 

memcached (pid  14784) is running...
```

Then restarted

```
service httpd restart
```

But when I try to use memcached on software(prosper202) I get

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCapabilities() on a non-object in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/******_com/3rd-parties/wurfl/WURFL/CustomDeviceRepository.php on line 72
```

I don't know whats causing it.

Here is my WURFL configuration file

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/202-config.php');

$configuration = array(
    // WURFL File Configuration
    'wurfl' => array(
        'main-file' => 'wurfl.zip',
        'patches' => array("web_browsers_patch.xml"),
    ),
    // Persistence (Long-Term Storage) Configuration
    'persistence' => array(
        'provider' => 'mysql',
        'params' => array('host'=>$dbhost,
                  'port'=>3306,
                  'db'=>$dbname,
                  'user'=>$dbuser,
                  'pass'=>$dbpass),
    ),
    // Cache (Short-Term Storage) Configuration
    'cache' => array(               
        'provider' => 'memcache',
        'params' => 'host='.$mchost.',port=11211,namespace=wurfl',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Are you able to post your config settings for WURFL?  I believe your issue is with your configuration of WURFL and not with your installation of memcached itself.

Comment: I see. I added the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!  Your issue is not with your installation of `memcached`.  Keep in mind that `memcache` and `memcached` are two different caching mechanisms.

You'll want to make sure that your server has `memcache` or `apc` installed for WURFL to be able to cache properly.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I can't find a guide to install "memcache" for centOS anywhere. Do you know a guide by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Type the following to see if memcached exists:
`which memcached`

Check the memcached version:
`memcached -h`